# How to differentiate the Home Screen widget tap and Force touch widget tab?

Tags: ios, objective-c, widget, ios-app-extension, 3dtouch

I'm developing a `Single View iOS application` using `Objective C`, I'm using widgets and 3d Touch `UIApplicationShortCutItems` in my app. I want to differentiate the widget tap via Home screen and via `3D touch.` After tapping the widgets in both the ways the `openURL` method on `Appdelegate` is calling by default. I don't know how to differentiate those taps. is it possible to get the title of `Widget`? Please hep me

Answer (score 0):

For Shortcut item we have delegate method `performActionForShortcutItem` for handling action method. So from there you can handle the shortcut item action.